# Communications strategy: Linux to .Net over SSL

Tags: .net, linux, wcf, sockets

We have two machines which need to communicate: a Linux based gateway, and a windows server based application.  The software on the windows machine side is .NET based.

We currently have communications working over basic tcp/ip sockets using a custom protocol.

The problems I have with this are:

1) working with raw sockets is difficult to pull off effectively - what higher level abstractions might we be able to leverage?

2) we have a future requirement of implementing SSL secured communications - my impression is that this will be difficult to do when working at this level

If you were going to implement secure communications between Linux and .net, what technology stacks on both platforms might you use?

Some other potentially useful pieces of information:

- I am a .Net developer with almost no  experience in linux (other people will implement the Linux portion)
- the Linux gateway should be assumed to be be behind a firewall (connections must originate from the gateway)
- communications will be frequent - for example exchanging data once per minute
- the windows platform software is ultimately the one requesting data.  (so perhaps a long polling strategy might be appropriate)

If the gateway was .net based, I imagine I would be leveraging wcf and wsdualhttpbinding.  Given that it's Linux, what strategy would you recommend?  (Any merit in libcurl+long polling+wcf?)

Edit:  some different google queries have uncovered gSoap.  Perhaps this is what I'm looking for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up going with node.js and websockets for realtime communication, and a REST based service to satisfy some separate request/reply type needs.